# Does the lateinit RecyclerView need initialization in the quickstart-android database app?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, kotlin

When I run the quickstart-Android Firebase database starter app, downloaded from the Firebase github repo, the app crashes immediately whether I choose to run (from a dialog) either the Java version or the Kotlin version. In the Kotlin version, it crashes because the RecyclerView in the PostListFragment has not been initialized. What might be the problem here, and is this a common problem?

[image: the code showing RecyclerView in PostListFragment]

Comment: Well where is it initialized? Is it ever initialized?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @.

Answer (score 1):

Great catch! You're right, this was a mistake.

Fixed here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/pull/739